# How to use Power Functions with Mindstorms EV3?

Tags: mindstorms, power-functions

Having [learned](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/News/ReadMore/Default.aspx?id=476781) that Mindstorms EV3 doesn't work directly with Power Functions,

> Q: Can you use Power Functions motors with the EV3 programmable brick?
>
> A: No, the connector does not match.

I still wonder what could be possible workarounds to use them together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this with these two parts:

- https://brickset.com/sets/8528-1/Converter-Cables-for-Mindstorms-NXT
- https://brickset.com/sets/8886-1/Extension-Cable

Comment: 8886 | (8871 & 8528) http://powerfunctions.lego.com/en-us/faq/default.aspx

Comment: How does this accomplish anything? The cables are incompatible. Bad answer and non-helpful. @guestguy123's answer was better, even without details (which I added).

Comment: As of Nov 2014, the top link doesn't work.  And, honestly, I don't think this was ever a valid solution.

Comment: @Nick2253 The top link has since rotted. I've updated it to the new location.

Comment: Just to confirm (as auselen's link to the FAQ points out) this *is* the LEGO approved way of connecting PF Mindstorms parts.

Comment: That FAQ entry is for the NXT not the EV3.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150122045709/http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Converter-Cables-for-LEGO-MINDSTORMS-NXT-8528

Comment: I can confirm 8528 and 8886 combination works, as long as you alter the speed of the motor. See David Lechner's answer for more details.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned by @guestguy123 and @eficker, it is easy to combine an EV3 cable and a PF cable to make a custom cable that allows the EV3 to control. This can even be done without soldering - I just twist the wires together and tape them with electrical tape. The full schematic is here:
[image: Schematic for cable]

All you need is 2 resistors (1x1kOhm and 1x10kOhm) which are cheap to get at your local electronics store (e.g. Radioshack or Maplin's) and the willpower to cut through 2 good Lego wires (1 PF cable and 1 EV3 cable). But once you do, it recognizes a PF motor as an NXT style unregulated motor and you can send it commands.

Comment: forgot to mention that I snipped that image from the youtube video - not my work ;)

Comment: Do the resistors avoid the timeout problem mentioned in David Lechners answer?

Comment: I have used my modified cables regularly and never encountered that problem, so I think the answer to your question is Yes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use 3rd party modules:

- [HiTechnic NXT IRLink Sensor](https://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NIL1046)

  - control PF motors using PF IR receiver
  - EV3 blocks
  - Lejos [IRLink](http://www.lejos.org/ev3/docs/lejos/hardware/device/IRLink.html) class
- [MindSensors PF Motor controller for NXT (PFMate)](http://www.mindsensors.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=107)

  - control PF motors using PF IR receiver
  - No EV3 blocks (yet)
  - Lejos [PFMateMotor](http://www.lejos.org/ev3/docs/lejos/hardware/device/PFMateMotor.html) class
- [Mindsensors GlideWheel PF Motor controller for NXT or EV3](http://www.mindsensors.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=153)

  - can power PF motor directly from EV3
  - PF motor can be used as regulated motor (servo)
  - EV3 blocks
  - Lejos [MindsensorsGlideWheelMRegulatedMotor](http://www.lejos.org/ev3/docs/lejos/hardware/motor/MindsensorsGlideWheelMRegulatedMotor.html) class

Or third party cable [NXT to PF Cable](http://www.robotshop.com/en/firgelli-technologies-nxt-to-pf-cable.html) (however I am not 100% sure if it will work with EV3). Accoring to [answer on lejos forum](http://www.lejos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=7177#p26075) it should work with Lejos [RCXMotor](http://www.lejos.org/ev3/docs/lejos/hardware/motor/RCXMotor.html) class.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect the Power Functions motor to the EV3 with a [LEGO 8528 cable](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Converter-Cables-for-LEGO-MINDSTORMS-NXT-8528) and a [LEGO 8886 cable](http://powerfunctions.lego.com/en-us/Products/Default.aspx#8886).

[image: LEGO 8528 cable]

[image: LEGO 8886 cable]

In addition to the cables, you need to know how to trick the software. You can use the unregulated motor block, but it will stop after a short time (1 second or so). You have to constantly change the speed to keep the motor powered.

Here is a simple example to run the motor at 75% of full power:

[image: Unregulated motor loop]

Using a single unregulated motor in a block like this won't work because the power value does not change. It seems that changing the power value is what resets the timeout on the EV3.

Answer (score 2):

this explains how to make a conversion cable:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ns3TODgRlCE

You take a cable from the EV3 and a power functions cable, add some resistors and solder it up. Not a tough mod, but you do have to sacrifice two cables to the cause. Although, the possibilities are worth it imo, as you can now control a lego train or other power functions sets with EV3.

Comment: Can add details (in your answer) about how this cable is made before referring to this external link?