# Connect 39k3 powerpack to 417j3 motor

Tags: motor

I'm new to lego.  Trying to connect the powerpack 39k3 from 42009 Crane to a 417j3 motor.  Is a 8528 Converter Cables for Mindstorms NXT the right cable?

Is there a way to hack a phone connector onto a power cable?  Where would I find the wiring diagram?

Many thanks,

Joe

Comment: Hi Joetest - I assume the powerpack you're referring to is [4506078: Batterybox 4X11X7](http://brickset.com/parts/4506078) - but I'm not sure which motor you mean - where did you get the part numbers from? In which case, it's probably a duplicate of [How to use Power Functions with Mindstorms EV3?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2325/56)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with these two parts:

- http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Converter-Cables-for-LEGO-MINDSTORMS-NXT-8528 [image: 8528]
- http://powerfunctions.lego.com/en-us/Products/Default.aspx#8886 [image: 8886]