# Cheapest and Simplest way to build a LEGO Technic car?

Tags: technic, building, motor

Having no LEGO Technic parts at all, I'm looking for the cheapest and simplest way to build a LEGO Technic car which can be combined with two Lego Technic motors to drive forward and backward (phase 1) and to steer to left and right (phase 2).

I see two possibilities:

- Buy a complete LEGO Technic product (which one can you recommend?)
- Get all the parts needed online (which parts do I need?)

I would like to combine the two motors with my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet is to start with [42048 Technic Race Kart](http://brickset.com/sets/42048-1/Race-Kart) and a [8293 Power Functions bundle](http://brickset.com/sets/8293-1/Motor-Set). This gives you just one motor, but that's enough for propulsion (going back and forth).

[image][image]

You would need to look into a motor driver board (for example the [DRV8835](https://www.pololu.com/product/2135)) for the motor, and look at schematics for a power functions cable mod to be able to drive the motor directly from the RPi - see [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/how-to-use-power-functions-with-mindstorms-ev3/7051#7051) for several suggestions on how to do this..

[image]

For steering you can look into a [88004 Servo Motor](http://brickset.com/sets/88004-1/Servo-Motor), or use a normal Medium motor with extremely fine control or a good set of gears to be able to make small steering adjustments.

[image]

Comment: Amazing as usual, Phil!

Comment: Note that you will end up with a big set of power functions parts on a small chassis - the go cart is big enough to carry them, but not by a large margin. The two photos are not at the same scale.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. Having read some tutorials I'm now thinking about getting the "BrickPi", which will help connecting Lego motors and sensors to my RaspberryPi. In this case I wouldn't need the motor driver board. This is not the cheapest solution but it looks very simple to me.

Comment: Yes, the BrickPi is a great solution as well. And to @Móż point: yes, it becomes quite cramped but if you remove the seat and the fake engine, there is enough space to place the motor and the battery box. I have done this in my classroom program.

Comment: Oh, you might want to add the BrickPi details as an answer to this post as well - could be helpful. @mosquito87