# Power Function Converter Cable for LEGO MINDSTORMS

Tags: mindstorms, power-functions

This is a follow up to this question:
[How to use Power Functions with Mindstorms EV3?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/how-to-use-power-functions-with-mindstorms-ev3)

The question was asked in 2013 (5 years ago). Fast forward to 2018, the product that was suggested in the answer is retired:
https://shop.lego.com/en-US/Converter-Cables-for-LEGO-MINDSTORMS-NXT-8528

Is there a replacement for the retired product?

Is there any better option, other than what is shown in this video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ns3TODgRlCE

Comment: If cost is not a concern, there are a few for sale on BrickLink: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8528-1 (starting at a 400% markup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no replacement yet except soldering your own cable or using third party products. Basically the answers in that question of 5 years ago are all still valid. 
Mind that LEGO is transitioning to a new power functions system (with motors and sensors as in the boost and WeDo 2.0 products), perhaps we'll see solutions for that quite soon.

Comment: Would you be able to share a link to the article shows the new power function system? I invested in the existing function family, so I guess I will need to create converters for them as well.

Comment: LEGO hasn't officially announced anything yet. But, articles like [this](https://ramblingbrick.com/2018/02/01/all-aboard-power-functions-2-0-with-bluetooth-announced-at-nuremberg-toy-fair-rampant-speculation-follows/) make it sound like we should know more sometime in 2018.

Comment: Products already available:
WeDo 2.0:
https://education.lego.com/en-us/products/lego-education-wedo-2-0-core-set/45300
Boost:
https://www.lego.com/en-us/boost
Also an upcoming train set will have Power Functions 2.0:
https://brickshow.com/2018/01/power-functions-2-0-to-be-featured-first-in-upcoming-lego-city-train-sets/
Perhaps also check out the WeDo 2.0 faq, it clearly states that the new system is intended to replace the old Power functions, although no timeline has yet been set
https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/wedo-2/faqs#core