# Makeblock and LEGO PF cable synthesis

Tags: shopping, power-functions, compatibility, motor

My 10yo son and I have ventured into the realm of taking our LEGO hobby up a notch with robotics. We have built the makeblock mbot and adapted LEGO bricks and want to incorporate the Power Functions set we have.

My question is, does anyone have any insight on creating an RJ25 adapter cable that is plug and play with the PF motors? Before I start hacking, I figured I would ask and see what additional info may be available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Power Functions with Mindstorms EV3?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/how-to-use-power-functions-with-mindstorms-ev3)

Comment: Given that the official cables mentioned in the other question/answer are no longer available directly from LEGO I'm ok with seeing if there is a better current answer.

Comment: Last year there was already a follow up question to see if there was an alternative... 9858. Nothing new was added then except I pointed out that LEGO is moving away from power functions 1.0 ... so no alternative except soldering your own cable, for which the original question has links...